# Android/Cordova UUID reliability

Tags: android, ios, cordova, uuid, spoofing

I'm developing an Apache Cordova app that relies on the device UUID. A couple questions run through my mind but I unfortunately couldn't seem to find the answer anywhere.

- Is the obtained device.uuid same for every platform, since I'm planning to release it both for Android and iOS?
- Is the UUID given by Cordova the same as the OS?
- Is there any way to change/spoof the OS/Cordova UUID? (this is important for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on android it uses  `android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`

> public static final String ANDROID_ID Added in API level 3
>
> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the
>   user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the
>   lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset
>   is performed on the device.
>
> Note: When a device has multiple users (available on certain devices
>   running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely
>   separate device, so the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.

it can be altered on root devices. http://www.prophethacker.com/2014/08/how-change-your-android-mobile-device-id.html

On iOS cordova create a random string on the first run, the string is unique for your app only, and might change even on app updates.

> iOS Quirk
>
> The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
>   application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
>   re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
>   upgrade the app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
>   reliable value.

On iOS you can use my identifier for vendor plugin 
https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

It uses the native identifier for vendor 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you provide me additional info about altering the ID on rooted devices?

Comment: I've added this link to the answer http://www.prophethacker.com/2014/08/how-change-your-android-mobile-device-id.html

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering if there's any way to check if the ID has been changed / if it's different than the original.

Comment: You can store it on the localStorage or other place the first time you use it and compare it everytime you want to use it to check that it didn't change