# Cordova uuid returns different values for debug and signed APK

Tags: android, cordova, uuid

We have a Cordova app with some dependencies relies on `uuid` which we obtain using the [cordova-uuid-plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/)

But the problem is `device.uuid` returns different values on both debug and signed apks.
But as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219172/android-cordova-uuid-reliability), it may change when a factory reset is performed in the device

Comment: answer to your question here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/issues/112#issuecomment-717903898